# How to use gdal_calc to multiply raster by a float variable

Tags: gdal

```
gdal_calc = 'python ' + basedir + '/gdal_calc.py -A' +wind_img+ " -B" + r2+   " --outfile=" + basedir + "/n16_temp_img.tif " + "--calc=" + '"(A * B)" '+ "--type=Float32" + " --overwrite"
os.system(gdal_calc)
n16_temp_img = 'n16_temp_img.tif'
```

I am trying to multiply a raster by a float variable in python. If I use a number in the operation it works but once I replace the number with a predefined variable it will break.  (wind.img is the raster and r2 is the float variable )

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Use string formatting, e.g. `'command {}'.format(float_arg)`.  You can't concatenate a float to a string